# drastically improve speed to subset and summarize pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, indexing

I have a dataframe which has history of purchases
(dataframe in the last)

I have to generate a summary of purchases made by them on first date of thier coming, 2nd date, 1 week, 1 month and so on like below:

| purchaser | firstDay | secondDay | firstWeek | firstMonth | 6months | oneyear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | anil | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | mukesh | 1 | 0 | 1 | 7 | 0 |
| 2 | ravi | 8 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 1 |

what I have done is as below:
created a summary

```
summary=df.groupby('purchaser').agg('min').rename(columns={'date':'min'}).reset_index()
summary['oneday_date']=summary['min']+dt.timedelta(days=1)
summary['oneweek_date']=summary['min']+dt.timedelta(days=7)
summary['onemonth_date']=summary['min']+dt.timedelta(days=30)
summary['sixmonth_date']=summary['min']+dt.timedelta(days=183)
summary['year_date']=summary['min']+dt.timedelta(days=365)
```

and then iterated and counted for each purchaser.

```
%%time
result=[]
for num, row in summary.iterrows():
    purchaser=row['purchaser']
    mindate=row['min']
    oneday=row['oneday_date']
    oneweek=row['oneweek_date']
    onemonth=row['onemonth_date']
    sixmonth=row['sixmonth_date']
    oneyear=row['year_date']
    
    subdf=df[df['purchaser']==purchaser]
    
    count0=len(subdf[(subdf['date']>=mindate) & (subdf['date']<oneday)])
    count1=len(subdf[(subdf['date']>=oneday) & (subdf['date']<oneweek)])
    count2=len(subdf[(subdf['date']>=oneweek) & (subdf['date']<onemonth)])
    count3=len(subdf[(subdf['date']>=onemonth) & (subdf['date']<sixmonth)])
    count4=len(subdf[(subdf['date']>=sixmonth) & (subdf['date']<oneyear)])
    count5=len(subdf[subdf['date']>=oneyear])
    
    result.append([purchaser,count0,count1,count2,count3,count4,count5])
```

```
CPU times: user 13.2 ms, sys: 587 µs, total: 13.8 ms
Wall time: 11.9 ms
```

My actual data is 1000,000 times bigger than this.

What I have already tried is

- Indexing the dataframe on date `df=df.set_index('date')`
- Sorting the `subdf` on `dates`

both did not bring any speed improvement

full data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'purchaser':['anil', 'anil', 'anil', 'anil', 'anil', 'anil', 'anil', 'anil', 'anil', 'anil', 'anil', 'anil', 'mukesh', 'mukesh', 'mukesh', 'mukesh', 'mukesh', 'mukesh', 'mukesh', 'mukesh', 'mukesh', 'ravi', 'ravi', 'ravi', 'ravi', 'ravi', 'ravi', 'ravi', 'ravi', 'ravi', 'ravi', 'ravi', 'ravi', 'ravi'],
'article':['pencil', 'pencil', 'pencil', 'pencil', 'rubber', 'rubber', 'rubber', 'rubber', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'pencil', 'pencil', 'rubber', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'pencil', 'pencil', 'pencil', 'pencil', 'pencil', 'pencil', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'sharpner', 'rubber'],
'date':[1611316328000000000, 1612432758000000000, 1616319170000000000, 1622455063000000000, 1604242496000000000, 1604245635000000000, 1605421133000000000, 1570823168000000000, 1594919491000000000, 1604248351000000000, 1604237937000000000, 1604233396000000000, 1604251740000000000, 1601216201000000000, 1604232509000000000, 1604249925000000000, 1604246581000000000, 1603559931000000000, 1603946050000000000, 1603956529000000000, 1604228447000000000, 1604233557000000000, 1604212924000000000, 1604212924000000000, 1604212924000000000, 1612539904000000000, 1614939815000000000, 1614964750000000000, 1621581174000000000, 1604218928000000000, 1604222345000000000, 1604239015000000000, 1613635361000000000, 1604208994000000000]})
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: you need to use `groupby` if you are working on each `purchaser` individually, also share some data as code so we can contrive a solution for you

Comment: have provided link to sample data

Comment: no links, post it as code only, like `df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})` we are not going to click on any links you provide

Comment: check now..appended

Comment: you are not understanding, post the data as _code_. it should be in the form of `df = pd.DataFrame({etc...})`

Comment: @gold_cy: This is done

Comment: what is the `min` column, that is not defined in the sample data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240764/discussion-between-gupta-and-gold-cy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm:

1. Calculate the first date of purchase for each purchaser using `.groupby()`, then calculate the second date, first week, ... one year dates. Keep this in a second data frame.
2. Left join these dates to the original dataset containing all purchases on the "purchaser" column.
3. Calculate the columns desired based on these date columns in the all-purchase set df. This can now be done using vectorized operations, instead of iterating over the whole array, leading to a much faster run time.
4. `.groupby()` on purchaser and sum each column's counts to produce the final desired output.

Comment: Wow ! That was amazing ! Worked like a charm ! Reduced the time by half.

Comment: How did you visualise this solution ? If you can share

Comment: Great! The main thing to look for when improving runtimes around dataframe manipulation is to look for areas in the code that involve iteration and see how one can "vectorize" them. So in this case, the key was converting the logic that was previously done in the for loop iterating over each row into vectorized operations. See more about vectorization here (pandas is built on-top of numpy arrays): https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html